# Inner Functions captures outside variable?

Tags: python, function, scoping

```
def outer_function(some_function):
    def inner_function(arg):
        print arg
    return inner_function

def function_2(a):
    return a

x = outer_function(function_2)
x(3)
```

My issue here is that how is inner_function able to capture the argument which I passed to x which is 3. How is the inner function able to capture an outside function argument?

Comment: `function_2` is never used here, and is irrelevant.

Comment: Functions are first class objects in python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Agreed, I should have spent more time trying to understand the code rather than posting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner function isn't capturing an outer function argument.

```
x = outer_function(function_2)
```

x is now a reference to inner_function, which takes in an argument and prints it.

```
x(3)
```

This is the same as `inner_function(3)`, which just prints 3 so 3 is printed.

Comment: I feel so stupid here. After reading your answer it feels obvious what is happening.